# wordpress: adding data to a custom table using $wpdb

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to add a form data to a custom table with the following:

> Table name: wp_auctions
>
> Table fields : first_name, last_name

The file `registration_form.php` is the registration form.
The file `registration.php` is the file that is intended to add data to the database table called `wp_auctions`.

The problem is that data is not being added to the table after the form is submitted. Any help? what am I doing wrong?

It looks like `$wpdb->insert()` is failing to run.

Below are my two files:

**File: Registration_form.php**

```
<?php
/*
template name: Registration_form;
Author: Aboubacar DRAME
*/
?>

<?php 

$directory=get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); 

?>
<form method= "POST", action=<?php echo $directory. "/registration.php";  ?>>
    <label for="first_name"> First Name </label>
    <input type="text" id="first_name" name="first_name"/> </br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit the form" /> 
</form>
```

**File: registration.php**

```
<?php

function Insert_data(){

global $wpdb;

$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
$last_name  = $_POST['last_name'];

$wpdb->insert('wp_auctions', 
        array('first_name' => $first_name), 
               'last_name' => $last_name),
        array('first_name' => '%s',
               'last_name' => '%s')
     );
}

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
Insert_data();
} 

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `$wpdb->insert` code is incorrect, it should be

```
$wpdb->insert(
       'wp_auctions', 

        array('first_name' => $first_name, 
               'last_name' => $last_name
        ),

        array( '%s',
               '%s'
        )
     );
```

See the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#INSERT_rows) for more information